# Is &*vector::end() undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, iterator

I thought `&*vector::end()` was undefined behavior... until I saw [some post](http://blogofbrew.blogspot.com/2011/06/benchmarking-stl.html) refer to [Stroustrup's code](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/container_benchmark.cpp):

```
void vector_pointer_test(element_t* first, element_t* last, int number_of_times) 
{ 
       vector<element_t> container(first, last); 
       // &*container.begin() gets us a pointer to the first element 
       sort(&*container.begin(), &*container.end()); 
       unique(&*container.begin(), &*container.end()); 
}
```

Is dereferencing an `end()` iterator undefined behavior, or is it valid?

Comment: If Stroustrup does it, how can it be wrong?

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's what prompted me to ask, because I *really* thought this was (is?) wrong...

Comment: I think so too, but I tend to stay out of the language lawyer debates. It will be interesting to see an answer. I always thought the `end()` iterator was not dereferenceable.

Comment: Plain wrong in my view. Assuming container is not empty then `&*container.begin() + container.size()` is the right way to do it.

Comment: @jahhaj - `*container.begin()` is only defined if the container is not empty. You should use `container.data()` instead, or test for emptiness.

Comment: @Brangdon: Didn't jahhaj also clearly write, *"Assuming container is not empty"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour. That is, behaviour not defined by the C++ standard. It may be defined by the implementation. More likely, it will happen to work by chance in some situations and not others.

In this case, if the iterator is a raw pointer the compiler will likely optimise &*i into a no-op, so it will likely work. Stroustrup may have known his vector used raw pointers as iterators.

Even if the compiler doesn't optimise it away, in practice, it's only likely to fail if the vector's memory happens to be allocated to end at a segment boundary. (Or if the iterator implementation is written to check for being non-dereferenceable, eg for debugging purposes.)

In C++11 this should be written as:

```
sort(container.data(), container.data()+container.size());
```

Comment: I feel like it *couldn't* have been a pointer, because that would've made the test case pointless... he already had a test case for iterators, and if they were pointers then there would've been no point (no pun intended) in a separate test case. So I guess his code is UB?

Comment: Yes, it's undefined behaviour. Even if his local vector doesn't use pointers for iterators, a conforming implementation could, and the standard doesn't require anything that pointers can't provide.

Answer (score 7):

It's not necessarily undefined behavior, but it depends on the specific implementation of the iterator:

> C++03 24.1/5 Iterator requirements
>
> Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees that there is a
>   pointer value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any
>   iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last
>   element of a corresponding container.  These values are called
>   past-the-end values. Values of an iterator i for which the expression
>   *i is defined are called dereferenceable.  The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable.

The code in question has undefined behavior if `container.end()` is not dereferenceable.  Many times a vector's iterator will simply be a pointer - in those cases there's no undefined behavior.

Comment: Sure, the *pointer* exists, but the fact that there *exists* a pointer value has nothing to do with whether you can dereference it, right? Especially since your quote seems to imply it should *not* be seen as dereferenceable in general.

Comment: So `container.end()` is *allowed* to be dereferenceable but not *guaranteed*. Interesting. It stands to reason that `vector` iterators would have this property, as they're the most straight-forward implementation.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I don't think he's relying on implementation-specific behavior here though. What if the vector ends on a page boundary? Then the next page of memory might have some protection that's different from the current page, which is irrespective of the vector implementation (unless it goes out of its way to correct for this, which is very unlikely). Also, it's worth noting that the iterator is probably **not** a pointer here, since otherwise this test case would've been redundant.

Comment: A vector's end pointer would still not be derferencable in the general case though. I'm willing to bet no canonical stdlib implementations allow any `end()` iterator be dereferenced.

Comment: Also, what if the vector is empty?! (Though I assume that was probably assumed false here.)

Comment: @Mehrdad, even an empty vector is required to have valid iterators.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No one's debating the validity of the iterators though. We're talking about dereferencing them.

Comment: @GManNickG, taking the address of an invalid reference might work correctly even if the dereference itself would be invalid. It's a consequence of the typical CPU architecture and not of the C++ language itself.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Actually, it's more a consequence of the compiler optimizing it away, not the architecture or the language.

Comment: @Mehrdad, the compiler and the architecture are intimately related.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I would downvote this answer if I could. Dereferencing pointers can be undefined behaviour. For example, `int *p=0; int x=*p;` has undefined behaviour. An empty vector of ints may have both `begin()` and `end()` as null pointers.