# How does Stroustrup take a non-const reference to a temporary?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

In Stroustrup's C++ Programming Language book (3rd edition), in the Numerics chapter he shows the following code snippet:

```
void f(valarray<double>& d)
{
    slice_array<double>& v_even = d[slice(0,d.size()/2,2)];
    slice_array<double>& v_odd = d[slice(1,d.size()/2,2)];

    v_odd *= v_even;
    v_even = 0;
}
```

The problem is, `v_even` and `v_odd` are non-const references to temporaries, which isn't allowed. And attempting to compile this emits an error:

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'slice_array<double>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'slice_array<double>'
    slice_array<double>& v_even = d[slice(0,d.size()/2,2)];
                         ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I checked through all of the errata available online and there's nothing that touches upon this fundamental problem. Am I missing something? Did the language change in this regard since the book was printed (unlikely, since the book itself mentions the rule against non-const references to temporaries)? What's going on here?

---

If I modify the function to use values instead of references, e.g. `slice_array<double> v_even = ...`, then this actually compiles. However, it turns out my local C++ headers make the copy constructor public, whereas Stroustrup and various online references (cppreference.com, cplusplus.com) claim the copy constructor is private. I assume that means this solution is non-portable. This is reinforced by the fact that Stroustrup explicitly lists a code sample with non-reference variables and says this produces an error.

---

The C++98 spec ([PDF](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf)) declares `slice_array<T>` as having a private copy constructor. By 2005 (according to [this spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)), and presumably as part of C++03, this changed to a public copy constructor.

Comment: "_Did the language change in this regard since the book was printed_" The reference binding rule is very old; `valarray` is more recent. It looks like an error (by BS).

Comment: @curiousguy: The book has gone through 20 printings. I looked through all of the errata; 2 printings made changes to this function, but amusingly, the second change actually reverted the first. And neither change was related to the issue at hand.

Comment: "_The book has gone through 20 printings._" and it begins to converge?

Comment: It [also surprised me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751722/is-vectorend-undefined-behavior) to learn Stroustrup isn't perfect, I know.

Comment: @Anonymous: how incredibly offensive, presumptuous and ignorant.

Comment: @TonyDelroy:- If the question and comments keep changing by time I cant follow them always.First answer was in respect to first question,if things are not clearly mentioned, answers will show deflection. We belong to community;and hopefully not some support for CHANGE REQUEST.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of different issues with the original code sample, and also the declarations given in the book for a number of operators.

The 'best' solution I believe is to do as follows

```
void f(valarray<double>& d)
{
    const slice_array<double>& v_even = d[slice(0,d.size()/2,2)];
    const slice_array<double>& v_odd = d[slice(1,d.size()/2,2)];

    v_odd *= v_even;
    v_even = 0;
}
```

All operators on `slice_array<T>` are defined as `const` as they are not modifying the slice itself, but the contents. These are defined incorrectly in the book as non-`const`.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be published in errata(although the link is dead now).

However google is great, it shows a snap for a search like this "slice_array& v_even"

> Stroustrup: **Errata for 3rd printing of The C++ Programming** Language
>   www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_printing4.html
>   [Cached][Share] Shared on Google+.
>   View the post.
>   You +1'd this publicly.
>   Undo

```
void f(valarray<double>& d)
{
    slice_array<double>& v_even = d[slice(0,d.size()/2, 2)];
    slice_array<double>& v_odd  = d[slice(1,d.size()/2,2)];

    v_odd *= 2; // double ...
```

EDIT:-
Thanks for edit in question Kevin ,it is not an error anymore 
I can see in N3092 clearly mentioned (§ 26.6.1,Pg 944)

> **4.** Implementations introducing such replacement types shall provide
>   additional functions and operators as follows: 
> — for every
>   function taking a const valarray&, identical functions taking the
>   replacement types shall be added;
>  — for every function taking two
>   const valarray& arguments, identical functions taking every
>   combination of const valarray& and replacement types shall be
>   added.
>
> **5.** In particular, an implementation shall allow a valarray to be
>   constructed from such replacement types and shall allow assignments
>   and computed assignments of such types to valarray, **slice_array,**
>   gslice_array, mask_array and indirect_array objects.

Further my compiler is not giving any issue(presently VS 2010) with the code,compiles perfectly.

Comment: That referenced page is actually live [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_printing4.html), and it says to change `f()` to... and prints an exact duplicate of the function.

Comment: I think that thing was updated one, which google cached,may be some (Ctrl+C,Ctrl+V)error while shifting document ;)

Comment: Note that msvc is known to falsely being able to have non-const references to temporaries.

Comment: @PlasmaHH not falsely, it's an extension to the language.

Comment: @RedX: You can call every deviation from standard c++ an extension if you want, that doesnt change anything in the fact that its noncompliant.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: It's non-compliant if it can't compile valid C++ programs. There's nothing non-compliant about it happening to compile other programs too. That said, I'm not sure if this actually prevents the correct compilation of valid programs -- that's a possibility...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Of course you can construct valid programs that won't compile, or produce wrong results, depending on how exactly this "extension" is implemented, this might already fail in simple overload situations, but at least you will be able to write something up using sfinae that will fail.